# Must explicitly set engine if not passing in buffer or path for io

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I am a beginner, could you help me to see where the problem lies? So I think maybe `read_excel` have some problem but I can't solve it. When I run this program I get: *"Must explicitly set engine if not passing in buffer or path for io"*.

```
import pandas as pd
data=pd.read_excel("C:\test.xlsx".encode('UTF-8'))
count=len(data)
data2=data['LINE1']
print(data2.head(10))
```

I get the following error: 
[image: Excel Error]

**What could be the problem?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need only filename in [`read_excel`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_excel.html) with double backslash:

```
data=pd.read_excel("C:\\test.xlsx")
```

Or `r` for raw string:

```
data=pd.read_excel(r"C:\test.xlsx")
```